# Use Live Testing with MS Fakes

Tags: visual-studio-2017, microsoft-fakes

I have a project using Microsoft fakes for mocking. The Tests run in Visual Studio 2017 without a problem. When I start the new Live Testing all Tests fail with the Message:

> Unable to create instance of class MyTests. Error:
>   Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.UnitTestIsolation.UnitTestIsolationException:
>   Failed to resolve profiler path from COR_PROFILER_PATH and
>   COR_PROFILER environment variables.

Is there a way to get Fakes working with the Live Testing Feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Tests do not work with the Microsoft Fakes Framework, this is an intended limitation of Visual Studio, but Microsoft has [stated](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/10436/living-unittesting-fails-when-creating-a-microsoft.html) they're looking into adding support for it.